# Java Swing Game TT

Tags: swing

I am trying to have this quiz like game where user have 3 buttons to choose from. If they chose the wrong answer, an image bomb wil appear and immediately it wil automatically change to the next question and if they chose the corect one, it will also change to the next question. However, my problem here is that i do not know if i wrote my if...else statements correctly. When i run my program, it doesn't change to the next question and there is no bomb image appearing too. I tried many methods to solve this but i stil could'nt. I really need help.
Here is my code and the if... else statements is from line 244 to 388.

```
public class GamesQuestionPanel extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JLabel jLabelQuestion = null;
private JLabel jLabelScore = null;
private JLabel jLabelHeart1 = null;
private JLabel jLabelHeart2 = null;
private JLabel jLabelHeart3 = null;
private JButton jButtonAnswer1;
private JButton jButtonAnswer2;
private JButton jButtonAnswer3;
private JLabel jLabelDescription1;
private JLabel jLabelDescription2;
private JLabel jLabelDescription3;
private JButton jButtonAdd = null;
private JFrame myFrame = null;
private JLabel jLabelTimer = null;
private Timer t;
private TimerModel tm;
private int qn_num = 0;
private JLabel jLabelScore1 = null;
private JLabel jLabelQn;
private JButton jButtonEdit = null;
private static int answer1;
private int answer2;
private int answer3;
private int count=0;
int Score = 0;

public void Randomise() {
ArrayList<Integer> random = new ArrayList<Integer>();
try{
DBController db = new DBController();

//passing data source name
db.setUp("CFDatabase");
String g_question =" ";
String dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM GameQuestion WHERE g_question ='" + g_question + "'";

//for retrieve SQL use readRequest method
ResultSet rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);

if (rs.next()){
int g_questionNo =rs.getInt("g_questionNo");
random.add(g_questionNo);
System.out.println(random.get(g_questionNo));
}

}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

/**
* This is the default constructor
*/
public GamesQuestionPanel() {
super();
initialize();
}

public GamesQuestionPanel(JFrame f) {
this();
myFrame = f;
}

public GamesQuestionPanel(JFrame f, String s ){
this();
myFrame = f;
jLabelTimer.setText(s);
}

/**
* This method initialises this
* 
* @return void
*/
private void initialize() {
jLabelQn = new JLabel();
jLabelQn.setBounds(new Rectangle(13, 96, 55, 50));
jLabelQn.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18));
jLabelQn.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelQn.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelQn.setText("");

jLabelScore1 = new JLabel();
jLabelScore1.setText("");
jLabelScore1.setSize(new Dimension(83, 29));
jLabelScore1.setLocation(new Point(119, 438));

jLabelTimer = new JLabel();
jLabelTimer.setBounds(new Rectangle(17, 23, 199, 53));
jLabelTimer.setText("00:01:00");
jLabelTimer.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelTimer.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/timerbg.png")));
jLabelTimer.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 18));
jLabelTimer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
t = new Timer(1000, new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
tm.timeTick();
jLabelTimer.setText(tm.getTime());
if(tm.isTimeUp()){
t.stop();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HighScore: " + Score, "GameOver",
JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
int finalScore = Score ;
String display = Integer.toString(finalScore);
jLabelScore.setText(display);
tm.setTime("00:10:00"); 
JPanel panel = new ProgrammesEventsPanelEnq(myFrame);
myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
myFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
myFrame.getContentPane().validate();
myFrame.getContentPane().repaint();
}
}
});
tm = new TimerModel();
tm.setTime("00:01:00");
t.start();

jLabelDescription3 = new JLabel();
jLabelDescription3.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
jLabelDescription3.setLocation(new Point(483, 385));
jLabelDescription3.setSize(new Dimension(218, 33));
jLabelDescription3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelDescription3.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelDescription3.setForeground(Color.black);

jLabelDescription2 = new JLabel();
jLabelDescription2.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
jLabelDescription2.setLocation(new Point(244, 386));
jLabelDescription2.setSize(new Dimension(226, 33));
jLabelDescription2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelDescription2.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelDescription2.setForeground(Color.black);

jLabelDescription1 = new JLabel();
jLabelDescription1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 20));
jLabelDescription1.setBackground(new Color(238, 238, 238));
jLabelDescription1.setLocation(new Point(9, 386));
jLabelDescription1.setSize(new Dimension(225, 33));
jLabelDescription1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelDescription1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
jLabelDescription1.setForeground(Color.black);

jLabelHeart3 = new JLabel();
jLabelHeart3.setBounds(new Rectangle(611, 61, 45, 39));
jLabelHeart3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/heartshape.png")));
jLabelHeart3.setText("");

jLabelHeart2 = new JLabel();
jLabelHeart2.setBounds(new Rectangle(546, 61, 43, 40));
jLabelHeart2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/heartshape.png")));
jLabelHeart2.setText("");

jLabelHeart1 = new JLabel();
jLabelHeart1.setBounds(new Rectangle(482, 60, 44, 41));
jLabelHeart1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/heartshape.png")));
jLabelHeart1.setText("");

jLabelScore = new JLabel();
jLabelScore.setBounds(new Rectangle(25, 438, 83, 29));
jLabelScore.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
jLabelScore.setForeground(Color.black);
jLabelScore.setText(" Score:");

jLabelQuestion = new JLabel();
jLabelQuestion.setBounds(new Rectangle(71, 95, 618, 52));
jLabelQuestion.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
jLabelQuestion.setForeground(Color.black);

this.setSize(712, 500);
this.setLayout(null);
this.setBackground(Color.white);
this.add(jLabelQuestion, null);
this.add(jLabelScore, null);
this.add(jLabelHeart1, null);
this.add(jLabelHeart2, null);
this.add(jLabelHeart3, null);
this.add(getJButtonAnswer1(), null);
this.add(getJButtonAnswer2(), null);
this.add(getJButtonAnswer3(), null);
this.add(jLabelDescription1, null);
this.add(jLabelDescription2, null);
this.add(jLabelDescription3, null);
this.add(getJButtonAdd(), null);
this.add(jLabelTimer, null);
this.add(jLabelScore1, null);
this.add(jLabelQn, null);
this.add(getJButtonEdit(), null);

qn_num = 1;
GameQuestion g1 = new GameQuestion(qn_num);
g1.retrieveGameQuestion();
jLabelQn.setText("Q1.");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3()));

}

/**
* This method initialises jButtonAnswer1    
* 
* @return javax.swing.JButton   
*/
private JButton getJButtonAnswer1() {
if (jButtonAnswer1 == null) {
jButtonAnswer1 = new JButton();
jButtonAnswer1.setBackground(Color.white);
jButtonAnswer1.setSize(new Dimension(228, 214));
jButtonAnswer1.setLocation(new Point(5, 164));
jButtonAnswer1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
jButtonAnswer1.equals("answer1");
qn_num = qn_num + 1;
GameQuestion g1 = new GameQuestion(qn_num);
g1.retrieveGameQuestion();

if((jButtonAnswer1.isSelected()) && (g1.getG_correctAnswer() == answer1))
{
jLabelQn.setText("Q" + qn_num + ".");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3())); 
//jButtonAnswer1.removeAll();
}
else if((jButtonAnswer1.isSelected()) && (g1.getG_correctAnswer() != answer1))
{
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/explode.png")));
int delay = 100;
try
{
Thread.sleep(delay);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e1)
{
e1.printStackTrace();
}
jLabelQn.setText("Q" + qn_num + ".");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jButtonAnswer1.removeAll();
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3())); 
}
}
});
}
return jButtonAnswer1;
}

/**
* This method initialises jButtonAnswer2    
* 
* @return javax.swing.JButton   
*/
private JButton getJButtonAnswer2() {
if (jButtonAnswer2 == null) {
jButtonAnswer2 = new JButton();
jButtonAnswer2.setBackground(Color.white);
jButtonAnswer2.setSize(new Dimension(228, 214));
jButtonAnswer2.setLocation(new Point(240, 164));
jButtonAnswer2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
jButtonAnswer2.equals("answer2");
qn_num = qn_num + 1;
GameQuestion g1 = new GameQuestion(qn_num);
g1.retrieveGameQuestion();
if((jButtonAnswer2.isSelected()) && (g1.getG_correctAnswer() == answer2))
{
jLabelQn.setText("Q" + qn_num + ".");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jButtonAnswer1.removeAll();
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3())); 
}
else if((jButtonAnswer2.isSelected()) && (g1.getG_correctAnswer() != answer2))
{
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/explode.png")));
int delay = 100;
try
{
Thread.sleep(delay);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e1)
{
e1.printStackTrace();
}
jLabelQn.setText("Q" + qn_num + ".");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jButtonAnswer1.removeAll();
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3())); 
}
}
});
}
return jButtonAnswer2;
}
/**
* This method initialises jButtonAnswer3    
* 
* @return javax.swing.JButton   
*/
private JButton getJButtonAnswer3() {
if (jButtonAnswer3 == null) {
jButtonAnswer3 = new JButton();
jButtonAnswer3.setBackground(Color.white);
jButtonAnswer3.setSize(new Dimension(228, 214));
jButtonAnswer3.setLocation(new Point(474, 163));
jButtonAnswer3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
jButtonAnswer3.equals("answer3");
qn_num = qn_num + 1;
GameQuestion g1 = new GameQuestion(qn_num);
g1.retrieveGameQuestion();
if((jButtonAnswer3.isSelected()) && (g1.getG_correctAnswer() == answer3))
{
jLabelQn.setText("Q" + qn_num + ".");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jButtonAnswer1.removeAll();
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3())); 
}
else if((jButtonAnswer3.isSelected()) && (g1.getG_correctAnswer() != answer3))
{
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/HealthOK/ui/images/explode.png")));
int delay = 100;
try
{
Thread.sleep(delay);
} 
catch (InterruptedException e1)
{
e1.printStackTrace();
}
jLabelQn.setText("Q" + qn_num + ".");
jLabelQuestion.setText(g1.getG_question());
jLabelDescription1.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription1());
jButtonAnswer1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image1()));
jButtonAnswer1.removeAll();
jLabelDescription2.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription2());
jLabelDescription3.setText(g1.getG_imageDescription3());
jButtonAnswer2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image2()));
jButtonAnswer3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(g1.getG_image3())); 
}
}
});
}
return jButtonAnswer3;
}
/**
* This method initializes jButtonEdit   
* 
* @return javax.swing.JButton   
*/
private JButton getJButtonAdd() {
if (jButtonAdd == null) {
jButtonAdd = new JButton();
jButtonAdd.setBounds(new Rectangle(591, 9, 90, 39));
jButtonAdd.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
jButtonAdd.setText("Add");
jButtonAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
t.stop();
JPanel panel = new GamesCreatePanel(myFrame);
myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
myFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
myFrame.getContentPane().validate();
myFrame.getContentPane().repaint();

Object admin = null;
if(getName() == admin) {
jButtonAdd.setVisible(true);
}
else {
jButtonAdd.setVisible(false);
}
}
});
}
return jButtonAdd;
} 

/**
* This method initializes jButtonEdit   
* 
* @return javax.swing.JButton   
*/
private JButton getJButtonEdit() {
if (jButtonEdit == null) {
jButtonEdit = new JButton();
jButtonEdit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 31));
jButtonEdit.setSize(new Dimension(90, 39));
jButtonEdit.setText("Edit");
jButtonEdit.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 16));
jButtonEdit.setLocation(new Point(492, 9));
jButtonEdit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
t.stop();
String a = jLabelQuestion.getText();
String b = jButtonAnswer1.getText();
String c = jButtonAnswer2.getText();
String d = jButtonAnswer3.getText();
String f = jLabelDescription1.getText();
String g = jLabelDescription2.getText();
String h = jLabelDescription3.getText();
GameQuestion game = new GameQuestion();
game.setG_question(a);
game.setG_image1(b);
game.setG_image2(c);
game.setG_image3(d);
game.setG_imageDescription1(f);
game.setG_imageDescription2(g);
game.setG_imageDescription3(h);
JPanel panel = new GamesEditPanel(myFrame, a, game);
myFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
myFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
myFrame.getContentPane().validate();
myFrame.getContentPane().repaint();
}
});
}
return jButtonEdit;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but there is way too much code to look through. You need to narrow down the problem more. Also, if this is homework, it should be labeled as such.

Comment: Also: indent your code properly. It's unreadable as is. And don't ever sleep in the event dispatch thread. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 1):

This code is way too long to go through it, but a quick look at your `if` statements reveals you are checking whether a `JButton` is selected. What you probably want is adding an `ActionListener` to the `JButton`, which will be called when the user clicks the `JButton`. In the `ActionListener` you can then check whether the correct answer was given and proceed, or show the 'bomb image'.

I suggest you take a look at the [Swing button tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and more specifically the [`JButton` part of the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#jbutton)